# DBus: returning a file descriptor

Tags: glib, file-descriptor, dbus

I want to implement a DBus service that returns a file descriptor, but this error is raised:

```
** (process:3419): WARNING **: Cannot marshal type "(null)" in variant
** (process:3419): CRITICAL **: unable to append OUT arg of type GValue for create_connection: ((GValue*) 0x647730)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6fcd5b9 in g_type_check_value ()
```

from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0

The interface I have implemented looks like this:

```
<node name="/org/designfu/IceService">
  <interface name="org.designfu.IceService">
    <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.CSymbol" value="ice_service"/>
    <method name="create_connection">
      <!-- This is optional, and in this case is redunundant -->
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.CSymbol" value="ice_service_create_connection"/>

      <arg type="b" name="controlling_mode" direction="in" />

      <arg type="b" name="upnp" direction="in" />

      <arg type="s" name="dbus_path" direction="out" />
      <arg type="s" name="username_fragment" direction="out" />
      <arg type="s" name="password" direction="out" />
      <arg type="v(h)" name="send_fd" direction="out" />
      <arg type="v(h)" name="recv_fd" direction="out" />
    </method>
  </interface>
</node>
```

and this is my implementation:

```
gboolean ice_service_create_connection(IceService *obj,
  const gboolean controlling_mode,
  const gboolean upnp,
  char **dbus_conn_path,
  char **username_fragment,
  char **password,
  GVariant **send_fd,
  GVariant **recv_fd,
  GError **error)
{
  IceConnection *conn;
  gboolean res;

  conn = g_object_new(ICE_CONNECTION_TYPE, 
    "controlling-mode", controlling_mode,
    "upnp", upnp,
    NULL);

  /* register dbus path */
  char uuid_str[] = "123";
  char dbus_path[512];
  g_snprintf(dbus_path, 512, "/org/designfu/IceService/object/%s", uuid_str, NULL);
  dbus_g_connection_register_g_object(bus, dbus_path, G_OBJECT(conn));

  /* set output parameters */
  *dbus_conn_path = g_strdup(dbus_path);
  res = ice_connection_get_local_credentials(conn, username_fragment, password);
  g_assert(res);

  *send_fd = g_variant_new("(h)", conn->their_sock[SEND]);
  *recv_fd = g_variant_new("(h)", conn->their_sock[RECV]);
  g_assert(*send_fd);
  g_assert(*recv_fd);

  return TRUE;
}
```

If I leave out the send_fd and recv_fd output parameters, the functions works like a charm.
However, somehow I have an error in passing the file descriptors to the dbus.

The descriptors were created using

```
  int domain = AF_LOCAL;
  int type = SOCK_STREAM;
  int protocol = 0;
  err = socketpair(domain, type, protocol, sock);
```

Does anyone have a clue what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v(h)` doesn't look like a valid [DBus type signature](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#type-system), are you sure you don't mean `(h)`?

Comment: If I just use `(h)` in the XML file, `dbus-binding-tool` raises this error: `process 25994: arguments to dbus_signature_iter_recurse() were incorrect, assertion "dbus_type_is_container (dbus_signature_iter_get_current_type (iter))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-signature.c line 213.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.`

Comment: Turns out that `dbus-binding-tool` cannot handle file descriptors and you should use `gdbus-codegen` instead! Then it finally works with `h` without parentheses!

Comment: `(h)` means "a structure containing one field of type h". Wrapping primitive types into a structure is usually used when handling enum values to prevent clients from confusing them with plain integers. As for descriptors, I don't see much sense in using `(h)` instead of `h`.